# What's the evidence for moving finger horizontally in tashahhud?

Tags: salat, tashahhud

I believe Malikis do this however I saw a brother who crossed his hands doing the index finger movement not vertically like most people but left to right to left to right... Malikis pray with hands by their side in Qiyam.

Answer (score -2):

this  move  like a hummer  on the satans head (Devils head)

while you are  praying 
a devil  call  (Khanzab)  stand  next to you and start to  remember you things you forgot it   to  take your  attentions and  destroy  your focus

so  when  you  end your  Sallat  (Pray)

and  sit to tashahud    this move  like  a hummer  on his head
and  when you reach  اشهد ان لا اله الا الله و ان محمدا رسول الله    you put ur finger up

و الله اعلم

Comment: OP clearly asks about an evidence!